# Is there any possible way to get meta tags(OPEN GRAPH) from server side php into angularjs SPA?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, facebook

I had been searching for this since long but ain't able to figure it out.. I have got a ready website built in angularjs using all the best practices and the server side is PHP CI.

Now what I am suppose to do is to get them the opengraph meta tags into the head section.

I could easily manage it using jquery ofcourse but the problem arises when the facebook scraper crawls over the page.

As it is a single page Application, there is gonna be only one `head` hence its not possible for me to mention it on any other html any how... And as it's HTML I cannot let php render the page..

I have tried to search for the answer and ultimately got to

http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/171/enable-rich-social-sharing-in-your-angularjs-app

But this is not possible for me to use.

I also read about the facebook opengraph pointer using

```
<link rel='opengraph' href='DESTINATION URL'>
```

But it says that all the basic tags need to be mentioned into the source and the additional tags can be obtained from destination url.

Is there any way I can solve this problem?

Comment: If you want to share individual pieces of content via URL, then all those pieces of content need to have an individual URL. And server-side rendering as outlined in the article you linked to, is the way to do that. Why it is “not possible” for you to use that (or something similar), you did not explain with one word (therefor I’ll vote to close as unclear what you’re asking.)

Comment: @CBroe as developers, we are suppose to answer our superiors.. if i mentioned that its not possible, then what is there to argue about it? And You got a lot of reputation.. may be you could be a moderator... but that doesn't stop me from asking my question... Kindly answer if you know.

Comment: I _did_ already answer your question. You will need some sort of server-side rendering, so that the scraper can request individual URLs that deliver individual sets of meta data. Your only other option would be to not use OG meta data, but let visitors publish your content via the Feed dialog, which still allows to specify all that data at run-time. (Although I would not rely on this too much, it might be that they disable this at some point, as they already did for the Share dialog.)

Comment: @CBroe Perfect.. Could the feed dialog could do the thing... can you post it in answer?

Comment: @Cbroe.. If i answer it will take 2 days to get it approved...

Answer (score 2):

Here is the easiest way beyond sharesocial.in

Follow this link
http://sharelinkgenerator.com/

You will get your work done here.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sharesocial.in directly allows us to do it. It allows to do it for any page, Amy website and for fb, LinkedIn, Google + and whatsapp.